# QtCreator and pkg-config

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I imported a makefile project into Qt creator for more productive development. When I use make in the terminal:

```
g++  Size3.o SteerableTests.o MyLib.o Tensor.o Cube.o Steerable.o -lUnitTest++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o steerable
```

It compiles successfully. But when using build option of QtCreator, it keeps saying that pkg-config can't find opencv. How to set the environment path for QtCreator?

```
11:35:21: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" all
g++  Size3.o SteerableTests.o MyLib.o Tensor.o Cube.o Steerable.o -lUnitTest++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o steerable
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is set in your shell, but not in *QtCreator*'s environment.

The easiest way around this that I can think of is to set it explicitly in the `Makefile`, e.g.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/the/path
```

To find `/the/path`, try `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in the shell or find `opencv.pc` using `locate` (preferably) or `find`.